# Scripting for LinkedIn Sales Navigator

Tags: python, scripting

I'm not a programmer (I'm starting to learn some coding, but I'm an absolute beginner).

Thing is that my work has lots of things that could be automated with scripting. I have to search lots of companies in Linkedin Sales Navigator which leads me to absolute boredom and alienation. I have to grab a spreadsheet, copy and paste every day, and I feel kind of stupid doing something that could be easily automated.

I have thought of automating this stuff, but I don't know where to start. A friend of mine told me that Stack Overflow could help me to know where I can start. I did my research but didn't found anything profitable, maybe this is due to my lack of knowledge.

Summarizing: I need the guides to create a Script that copy a spreadsheet field to a browser field and extract the results from it and paste it out to the adjacent fields of the same spreadsheet, with the info extracted from LinkedIn. Where I can start? Thanks for your comprehension.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! you should look in the help center how to ask a question if you want a good answer ;). You are voted down by people because you question doesn't concern stackoverflow, and is more like a job assigment. If you want help, try something yourself (looking at python tutorial) and post it here to get help if you can't do it.

Comment: @Guillermo Gómez De Salazar https://medium.com/p/exporting-leads-informations-from-linkedin-sales-navigator-d38d3602e5b3

Answer (score 0):

Python is perfect the task the described above, I would recommend looking at following:

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/

Automate the boring stuff with python (book)

These should get you started.

Comment: Thank you, that is the book I acquired for learning Python indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Here a description of a tool that automate the extraction of leads and accounts:

https://medium.com/p/exporting-leads-informations-from-linkedin-sales-navigator-d38d3602e5b3